# PowerShell - List all computers & which users are administrators

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a powershell script that:

- Finds all computers in the domain
- Queries each computer to determine what groups/users are in the Administrators group
- Lists each user/group/computer
- The columns should be: Username, GroupName, ComputerName, DomainName

Here's where I am at so far, but I'm looking for some help parsing the WMI results in a consistent fashion, or per

Here's the script so far:

```
$auditdir = "c:\temp\"
$tempfile = $auditdir + "computers.csv"

$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *)

$Table = @()
$Record = @{
      "MachineName" = ""
      "GroupName" = ""
      "DomainName" = ""
      "Username" = ""
    }
Foreach ($computername in $computers){

    $computername = $computername.name
    $ADMINS = get-wmiobject -computername $computername -query "select * from win32_groupuser where GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='$computername',Name='administrators'""" | % {$_.partcomponent}

    foreach ($ADMIN in $ADMINS){

        Write-Host "Output current admin"
        $admin
        Write-Host "Clean up current admin"
        $admin = ($admin | Out-String)
        $admin = $admin -replace 'cimv2', '' -replace 'Win32','' -replace 'useraccount','' -replace 'root','' -replace $computername,'' -replace ',','' -replace "`n|`r" -replace $env:userdomain,'' -replace 'name','' -replace '=','' -replace ':','' -replace '_','' -replace '\\','' -replace '_','' -replace 'group','' -replace '""',''
        $admin.substring(8)
        $admin
        $admin = $admin | %{$_.split('"')[3]}
        $admin
        Write-Host "done with current admin"

        $Record."Machinename" = $computername
        $Record."Groupname" = $admin
        $Record."DomainName" = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
        $Record."UserName" = $admin.split("")[1]

        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord    
    }
$Table | Export-Csv $tempfile -NoTypeInformation    
}
```

Can someone please help me get to the finish line?

**Update 1:**
With Mathias's help, I've cast the results of the WMI query to a WMI type and can access items easier.

```
$auditdir = "c:\temp\"
$tempfile = $auditdir + "computers.csv"

$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *)

$Table = @()
$Record = @{
      "ComputerName" = ""
      "MemberName" = ""
      "DomainName" = ""
      "SID" = ""
    }
Foreach ($computername in $computers){

    $computername = $computername.name
    $ADMINS = get-wmiobject -computername $computername -query "select * from win32_groupuser where GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='$computername',Name='administrators'""" | % {$_.partcomponent}

    foreach ($ADMIN in $ADMINS){

        $admin = [WMI]$admin
        $admin

        $Record."ComputerName" = $computername
        $Record."MemberName" = $admin.name
        $Record."DomainName" = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
        $Record."SID" = $admin.SID

        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord    
    }
$Table | Export-Csv $tempfile -NoTypeInformation    
}
```

I seem to be running into an issue with domain admins group. It can't seem to be converted to WMI and then parsed.

Error is:

```
Cannot convert value "\\computername\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="domain",Name="Domain Admins"" to type
"System.Management.ManagementObject". Error: "Not found "
At C:\Users\f12admin\Desktop\computerlist.ps1:20 char:3
+         $admin = [WMI]$admin
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToWMI
```

Comment: What's up with `($admin |Out-String)` and `-replace` all over the place? Why don't you access `$admin.Name` directly instead?

Comment: Out-String was needed to use -replace.
-Replace was trying to be used to filter out the excess text in the query results.

Comment: No, I mean, why are you doing that in the first place? Why don't you just use the `Name` property?

Comment: The results of the WMI query don't seem to give me the ability to access the name property. I just tried it and it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Actually it seems to work when queried against the group result but not the user...

Comment: Cast it to `[wmi]` and you should be able to: `% {[wmi]$_.PartComponent}`

Comment: That worked really great! I've updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question - is there a reason you're using `Get-WMIObject` and not the `Cim` cmdlets? Does this need to run on PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: I've been working on getting PS2 out of the picture, can you give me an example of how it could work with cim?